# Python 3.7 doesn't seem to want to install (still shows 2.7.17?)

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install **Python 3.7** on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. Following these directions:

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.7
```

But after that completes, if I do:

```
root@west:~# python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

What am I doing wrong? If I try and install it again, it tells me its already installed?

```
root@west:~# sudo apt install python3.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3.7 is already the newest version (3.7.7-1+bionic1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are installed but there is a link pointed to python2.7.

If you do an `ls -l /usr/bin/python` it will point to python2.7 like below:

```
root@5d9377c79b0c:/# which python
/usr/bin/python
root@5d9377c79b0c:/# ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
root@5d9377c79b0c:/# which python3.7
/usr/bin/python3.7
```

Remove the link and create a new one to `python3.7`

```
rm /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python
```

> root@5d9377c79b0c:/# python --version
>   Python 3.7.5

Comment: Changing the `python` symlink put in place by the OS vendor to an incompatible version seems like it would break things that rely on python 2.7. Probably better to just use `python3` which I presume is in place.

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick :)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, I get what you're saying.  In this case, I had a base version of Ubuntu that didn't have python installed.  The installer for python2.7 created the link.  If Ubuntu comes without python installed I would assume Ubuntu isn't reliant on a python version.